# Accept keeps reverting

Tags: support, bug, accepted-answer

The OP of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398097/border-on-label-when-using-transparency-key/24403515?noredirect=1#comment37779563_24403515) tried to accept my answer, but says it keeps reverting back. Indeed I saw it blink and saw go my rep up and down. What's happening here ??

Comment: Did he try to accept it less than 15 minutes after asking the question?  You probably wouldn't even see it be accepted in this case, but it's worth asking.

Comment: My theory is that he's accidentally double-clicking instead of clicking.

Comment: @user0000000 The simplest explanation is usually correct. Or he's *really* committed to the bit with multiple attempts reverted in the same second over time. Possible, but unlikely in practice.

Comment: @user0000000, [Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor)

Comment: See the [post timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24398097/timeline). That user certainly *tried* to award the answer a mighty number of times!

Comment: @ Martijn: True. But I can't imagine any ill purpose or even just making fun behind it. I'll just wait and see..

Comment: Looks like he was really hammering away at the check-mark at 16:28.

Answer (score 4):

OP says:

- No doubleclicking was involved
- He got it working finally by switching from Chrome to IE for the purpose.

So:

> Don't assume malice, when Google suffices for an explanation